# Using sftp with socks5 proxy node.js

Tags: node.js, ssh, proxy, sftp

I have been looking at using the ssh2 module for sftp shipping of logs. However the cloud service hosting our app uses a rotating ip address range. So wanting to integrate the socks5 proxy service that is giving us the static ip address. I'm using the socksjs module to get the socks5 connection established, I'm getting the connection to the proxy, but I think I have the injecting of that socket connection for the sftp to use wrong.

Cheers,

Nik

```
var sockConn = new SocksConnection(connTargetSettings, connProxySettings);
connTargetSettings.sock = sockConn.outSocket;

var conn = new ssh2.Client();
conn.on("ready", function() {
    conn.sftp(function(err, sftp) {
        if (err) throw err;
        // you'll be able to use sftp here
        sftp.readdir("/", function(err, list) {
            if (err) throw err;
            // List the directory in the console
            console.dir(list);
            // Do not forget to close the connection, otherwise you'll get troubles
            conn.end();
        });
        // Use sftp to execute tasks like .unlink or chmod etc
    });
}).connect(connTargetSettings);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [socksv5](https://github.com/mscdex/socksv5) library(it's from creator of ssh2) to connect throw socks5 proxy.

Example:

```
var socks = require('socksv5'),
    SSHClient = require('ssh2').Client;

socks.connect({
  host: 'ssh.example.org', // destination
  port: 22,
  proxyHost: '127.0.0.1',
  proxyPort: 1080,
  auths: [ socks.auth.None() ]
}, function(socket) {
  var conn = new SSHClient();
  conn.on('ready', function() {
    conn.exec('uptime', function(err, stream) {
      if (err) throw err;
      stream.on('close', function(code, signal) {
      conn.end();
      }).on('data', function(data) {
        console.log('STDOUT: ' + data);
      }).stderr.on('data', function(data) {
        console.log('STDERR: ' + data);
      });
    });
  }).connect({
    sock: socket,
    username: 'frylock',
    privateKey: require('fs').readFileSync('/here/is/my/key')
  });
});
```

Comment: I had to use `npm install lee-elenbaas/socksv5 --save` to use the fork from @lee-elenbaas that works on new versions of node